# Unicorn Latency with Rails 4, Redis and Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, redis, unicorn, latency

I have been profiling my web application, and the latency is quite bad. I've observed that the initial page load can take between 200ms to over 1 seconds to resolve! Subsequent requests can be faster, but still rather slow ~300ms.

[image: Google Chrome Latency]

My stack consists of Rails 4, Ruby 2.0, Unicorn, Apache2, Postgres, Redis and Sidekiq (which uses redis).

I've read the following [information](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/examples/unicorn.conf.rb) which may be relevant. How does one restart a shared redis socket? Could this be responsible for the latency?

```
  # if preload_app is true, then you may also want to check and
  # restart any other shared sockets/descriptors such as Memcached,
  # and Redis.  TokyoCabinet file handles are safe to reuse
  # between any number of forked children (assuming your kernel
  # correctly implements pread()/pwrite() system calls)
```

Apache default:

https://gist.github.com/fogonthedowns/6588751

My Unicorn.rb file looks like this:

```
worker_processes 2
preload_app true
timeout 30
listen 5000

after_fork do |server, worker|
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

production.rb:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.precompile += %w( tag.js )
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "foo.com" }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "foo.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: "no-reply@foo.com",
    password: "foooo"
  }

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

What could be responsible for such poor latency?

Production.log

```
  Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (26.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 29.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
Started GET "/assets/google_button.jpg" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:19:36 +0000
Started GET "/tags/" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:19:38 +0000
Processing by TagsController#index as HTML
  Rendered tags/index.html.haml within layouts/application (12.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 16.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
Started GET "/assets/google_button.jpg" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:19:38 +0000
Started GET "/jason-wade-for-mayor" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:19:39 +0000
Processing by CommitteesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"jason-wade-for-mayor"}
  Rendered committees/show.html.haml within layouts/application (35.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 49ms (Views: 41.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
Started GET "/assets/committee-b8c8544f44424bd9e0234cd1a1fcd796.js" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:19:40 +0000
Started GET "/assets/google_button.jpg" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:19:40 +0000
Started GET "/jason-wade-for-mayor" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:19:54 +0000
Processing by CommitteesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"jason-wade-for-mayor"}
Redirected to http://redmeetsblue.us/
Filter chain halted as :beta_test rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:19:55 +0000
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (4.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 7.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/assets/google_button.jpg" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:19:57 +0000
Started GET "/assets/favicon.ico" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:19:58 +0000
Started GET "/jason-wade-for-mayor" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:20:10 +0000
Processing by CommitteesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"jason-wade-for-mayor"}
Redirected to http://redmeetsblue.us/
Filter chain halted as :beta_test rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:20:10 +0000
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (5.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 8.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/jason-wade-for-mayor/contributions/new" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:22:15 +0000
Processing by ContributionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"committee_id"=>"jason-wade-for-mayor"}
  Rendered contributions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (6.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 10.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
Started GET "/assets/google_button.jpg" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:22:15 +0000
Started GET "/tags/" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:22:18 +0000
Processing by TagsController#index as HTML
  Rendered tags/index.html.haml within layouts/application (28.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 153ms (Views: 36.6ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
Started GET "/assets/google_button.jpg" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:22:18 +0000
Started GET "/" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:22:22 +0000
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (11.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 13.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
Started GET "/assets/google_button.jpg" for 24.53.176.189 at 2013-09-18 04:22:22 +0000
Started GET "/" for 24.7.86.40 at 2013-09-18 04:23:04 +0000
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (8.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 13.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/assets/google_button.jpg" for 24.7.86.40 at 2013-09-18 04:23:04 +0000
Started GET "/assets/favicon.ico" for 24.7.86.40 at 2013-09-18 04:23:05 +0000
```

Comment: Can you post some of the log output?

Comment: which logs would you like to see?

Comment: Post the Rails log. And try profiling your app using New Relic. There's a free developer license.

Comment: I've added a few lines of Prod logs. I'm not sure its very useful.